# interpret full-width space as half-width space in bash

Tags: bash, osx, unicode

I have an alias `jp` for looking up Japanese words in the terminal via [myougiden](https://github.com/leoboiko/myougiden). Often I will be typing in Japanese in another application and will switch to bash to use the dictionary. However, when I have the Japanese keyboard turned on and try to input `jp 言葉`, OSX inputs `ｊｐ　言葉`, with full-width letters and spaces. This line then gets interpreted as a single command, which of course is not found. It is not convenient to switch back and forth between half-width romaji input, so I would rather bash interpreted the full-width input.

I can certainly add another alias for `ｊｐ`, but if bash can't interpret the full-width space then the command makes no sense. Is there any combination of aliases or settings that I can use to make bash interpret full-width spaces as regular half-width spaces?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this sort of problem, but can you just add the *full-width space* character to bash's `IFS` variable, which determines what separates fields.

Comment: That sounds promising! However, when I do `IFS="　"; jp　foo` it tells me: `-bash: jp　foo: command not found`. My `$LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: You probably need to set IFS on a line of its own, and preserve its original settings `IFS="<your space>$IFS"`. Is it possible to rewrite your `jp` as a simple shell script that reads one line from the input, then calls myougiden with that as parameter? It means 1 more <enter> to type.

Comment: I actually did set it on it's own line (I shortened it for the comment here). I could rewrite the script, but then the problem would come up again for other commands that take Japanese input. Maybe IFS doesn't allow general unicode characters?

Comment: You could try using the unicode code (U+3000 it seems for space): `x=$(printf '\u3000'); IFS="$x$IFS"`. I tried `b="echo$x/foo"` after this and then `$b` got correctly executed as `echo /foo`.

Comment: Nope, `jp　hello` still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to add a binding in your `~/.inputrc` to replace the character by a space:

```
"\343\200\200": " "
```

You need to start a new bash shell to get the file reread. Or you type the equivalent command to the shell:

```
bind '"\343\200\200":" "'
```

The left-hand string is the utf-8 encoding of unicode u+3000 character which seems to be full-width space. If not you need to determine what the character code is your keyboard is generating.